# VIM Mappings. What does <c-g> stand for (it's not CTRL which is <C-g> and it's not Shift/Alt c)

Tags: vim

I feel like I'm rather stupid.

Essentially I've installed CtrlP and can open it but can't switch the mode because I don't know what it's shortcuts refer to on the keyboard.

The Capital C = CtrlP, F5 is F5, but c-f is not lowercase cf.

https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim

Comment: https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim is a more up to date fork

Comment: See `:help key-notation`.

Answer (score 6):

It is control - both `<C-` and `<c-` refer to control.

Comment: As simple as that, yep, I am a moron.